# VS2008 Net 3.5 C# Can't include NAudio.csproj : meaning of "$" and "=>"

Tags: c#, syntax, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, naudio

I use VS 2008 (I like its simplicity and speed) and I have a project I compile for Net 3.5. When trying to import the NAudio.csproj (link below) I get many syntax errors in the NAudio code on lines like:

```
throw new FormatException($"End Track event was not the last MIDI event on track {track}");
```

Unexptected character '$' (the whole line is underlined in red)

```
public int Tracks => events.Tracks;
```

; expected (the "=>" is underlined in red)

Can I use NAudio in VS 2008 and compile for Net 3.5?

[NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VS2008 only supports C# 3, which doesn't include either verbatim string literals or expression-bodied members.

However, that doesn't mean you can't *use* NAudio - you just won't be able to compile it yourself. You should use the [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NAudio), which does include a target for .NET 3.5.

On a side-note though, I'd *strongly* advise you to update to a more recent version of VS - you're missing out on a lot of new language features, as well as the ability to develop for .NET Core etc. Over time, fewer and fewer packages are likely to support .NET 3.5, and fewer projects will be able to compile using C# 3.

Comment: Thanks. I've never used nuget. I downloaded nuget 4.5.1 command line (later versions give me an error). I ran "nuget install naudio.1.8.4.nupkg" but I get "  NotFound https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3-gz-semver2/naudio.1.8.4.nupkg/index.json 575ms
Unable to find package 'naudio.1.8.4.nupkg'" What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @MrSparkly: I don't know the details of that - but another option would be to download the NuGet package directly and store it in a local package repository that you'd configure in VS. (You can extract the contents and add a reference to the DLL directly if you *really* want to, although I'd advise against it. A NuGet package is just a zip file with a specific layout.) This is another example of the problems you're likely to face by using very old versions of everything - I'd really encourage you to upgrade.

Comment: OK, I installed VS2017 and NAudio using the Package Manager. So far, VS2017 seems as fast as VS2008, so I may stick to it (but the "flat" GUI is still ugly). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a newer version of Visual Studio, that will allow you to make use of newer language features.

Set the "Target framework" property to ".Net Framework 3.5" to make the executable requiring the older framework version only. (In the Properties page of the project, select the "Application" tab, and there you'll find the "Target framework" combobox).